# "than" vs "other than"

Tags: grammar

When is the construction *other than* required, or preferable to simply *than*?

> There's not much we can do than wait.

This feels more correct:

> There's not much we can do other than wait.

But if I add "more" before "much", I'm unsure if omitting "other" seems better?

> There's not much more we can do than wait.

Although this still feels more correct:

> There's not much more we can do other than wait.

Comment: The _more_ and the _other_ are both **Comparative**. _Than_ can only occur in a comparative construction. No comparative, no _than_.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. Likewise, *else*: *There's not much else we can do than wait* (or *but wait*).